# Python How to create a Programm with time?

Tags: python

i want to create a program that calculate how many hours and minutes are left

for example

18:30 - 19:10 -> 0hours and 40minutes

```
class Uhrzeit():
    def __init__(self, von, bis):
        self.von = von
        self.bis = bis
        self.umrechnen()
    def umrechnen(self):
        master = 60
        stunden_bis,stunden_von = int(self.bis.split(":")[0]),int(self.von.split(":")[0])
        minuten_bis,minuten_von = int(self.bis.split(":")[1]),int(self.von.split(":")[1])
        print stunden_bis-stunden_von, minuten_bis-minuten_von
Uhrzeit("18:30","19:10")


>> 1 -20
```

Comment: Look at datetime and timedelta in the datetime module

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the datetime module, which makes things quite simple.

```
from datetime import datetime
time1 = datetime.strptime("18:30", "%H:%M")
time2 = datetime.strptime("19:10", "%H:%M")

diff = time2 - time1
print(diff)
```

> 0:40:00

Comment: Do you mean .strftime?

Comment: Not really - that allows turning a datetime to a string, but doesn't turn a string into a datetime object.